# Forwarding packets using iptables without hiding source ip

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, forwarding

I have a debian router with a wan interface (eth0) and a lan interface (eth1). I have configured it to masquerade certain packets from eth0 to eth1, but i want to keep the source ip instead of changing it to the router's lan ip. DNAT won't work (i think?) because i want to forward all traffic. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/523236/how-do-i-forward-nat-all-traffic-to-one-interface-ip-to-a-remote-ip) may help

Comment: no, i don't think so. if i curl one of the hosts from wan it still gets the source ip of the router.

Comment: so, you've implemented the accepted answer in that question, removing your masquerade of course, and it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not iptables DNAT or masquerading that "forwards" the packets anyway – iptables only translates packets that are *already* due to be forwarded by the kernel's network stack. If you have the system already working as a router, it means IP forwarding is set up correctly so you could literally **remove the masquerade rule** and get the desired result.

If things do not work, keep in mind that 1) preserving the original source means all destination hosts need an explicit route *back* to that source address, and that 2) there is a difference between not being able to send a packet and not being able to receive replies to it, and a basic `ping` *will not tell you* which one it is – a packet capture tool will.

Comment: Might also worth noting that  whitelisting rule should be added to filter/FORWARD

Comment: I assume they would already have that because it's already needed to make things work even *with* DNAT and/or masquerading...

Comment: thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding!